# the meaning of the output from iwlist scan

Tags: linux, wifi, wireless, wpa

i have a question to the output of iwlist scan. for instance i have the following result.
There are multiple entries with IE. What does the IE stand for? Becasue there are multiple entries i guess there are different encryption options for this Wifi. What are all options can be displayed there? "WPA Version 1","IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1","unkonw" what is about WEP? Or EAP? How this will be displayed?

```
      Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:F3:02:04:81
                ESSID:"Apple Network"
                Mode:Master
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=42/100  Signal level:-84 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C0217FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE : Information Elements

Refer to [Management Frames](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/networking/wireless/0596100523/4dot-802dot11-framing-in-detail/wireless802dot112-chp-4-sect-3),

> Management frames are quite flexible. Most of the data contained in
>   the frame body uses fixed-length fields called fixed fields and
>   **variable-length fields** called **information elements**. Information elements are blobs of data of varying size. Each data blob
>   is tagged with a type number and a size, and it is understood that an
>   information element of a certain type has its data field interpreted
>   in a certain way. New information elements can be defined by newer
>   revisions to the 802.11 specification;

[IEEE 802.11i-2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i) is standard that specifies security mechanisms for wireless networks.

[Wi-Fi Protected Access (WPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) is security protocol and security certification program.

sorry I can't find iwlist result with WEP and EAP.....

How about use `iw` command? [The n mode on “iwlist wlan0 scan”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/the-n-mode-on-iwlist-wlan0-scan)

Comment: i was check the    iw command. can be working too. in     iwlist i have additionally informations about the channel of the wifi.

Comment: you use the `sudo iw wlan0 scan?`